# How to returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 16

Tags: c#, java

What is the C# equivalent  of  Integer.toHexString()   from Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Format("{0:x}", x)` static method or `Int32.ToString("x")` method.

see the example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    int x = 4067;
    string s = x.ToString("x");
    Console.WriteLine(s);      // fe3

    s = String.Format("{0:x}", x);
    Console.WriteLine(s);      // fe3

    s = String.Format("{0:X}", x);
    Console.WriteLine(s);      // FE3

    s = String.Format("{0:x6}", x);
    Console.WriteLine(s);      // 000fe3
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following converts to hex

```
int myInt = 222;
string hexString = myInt.ToString("x")
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString)

Comment: It results in Hex which is base 16.